# Add each element in one vector with each element in a second vector

Tags: r

I would like to add each element in one vector with each element in another vector as follows, **but** avoid the for loops. Is there a simple method?

```
vadd <- function(vrow, vcol){
vmatrix <- matrix(nrow = length(vrow), ncol = length(vcol))
for(r in 1:length(vrow)){#rows
    for(c in 1:length(vcol)){#columns
        vmatrix[r, c] <- vrow[r] + vcol[c]
    }
}
return(vmatrix)
}

a <- c(1:10)
b <- c(3:4)
vadd(a, b)
```

Sincerely,
Brian

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you are looking for is `outer()`, as in:

```
> outer(a, b, "+")
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    4    5
 [2,]    5    6
 [3,]    6    7
 [4,]    7    8
 [5,]    8    9
 [6,]    9   10
 [7,]   10   11
 [8,]   11   12
 [9,]   12   13
[10,]   13   14
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the help everyone. These are great.

Comment: @user658733 If one of the three answers solves your problem, can you select one and accept it? To accept an answer, click on the tick/check mark on the left of an answer near the number showing the votes. Main reason for doing this is that if someone else finds your Q via a search they'll know if your question was answered satisfactorily or not?

Answer (score 3):

You can put `b` in a matrix and take advantage of R's recycling rules:

```
a + matrix(b, nrow=length(a), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one thing you can do:

```
a<-c(1:10)
b<-c(3:4)

matrix(b,length(a),2,byrow=TRUE)+a
```